# cesium-Convert `Ellipsoid` into `EllipsoidGraphics`

Tags: entity, cesiumjs

I am so confused about definition of these two `EllipsoidGraphics` and `Ellipsoid`
I want to add an simple  `Ellipsoid` into my map and find its intersection with a ray,
I know that I must add an entity to map,I also know that each entity can have `EllipsoidGraphics` property, But I don't know how to Convert `Ellipsoid`  into `EllipsoidGraphics`

Can some one helps me with it?
this is a sample code that I use but it does not show any thing

```
var elip =new Cesium.Ellipsoid(300000.0, 300000.0,200000.0);

var redSphere = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Red sphere with black outline',
    position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-107.0, 40.0, 300000.0),
    ellipsoid : {
        radii : elip,
        material : Cesium.Color.RED.withAlpha(0.5),
        outline : true,
        outlineColor : Cesium.Color.BLACK
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a minor tweak to specify the radii of the [Ellipsoid](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/EllipsoidGraphics.html) as a Cartesian3 property.

```
  var entity = viewer.entities.add({
    position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(126.966667, 37.55),
     ellipsoid : {
        radii : new Cesium.Cartesian3(300000.0, 300000.0, 200000.0),
        material : Cesium.Color.RED.withAlpha(0.5),
        outline : true,
        outlineColor : Cesium.Color.BLACK
    }
  });
  viewer.zoomTo(entity);
```

For clarification, ellipsoid is the field in the *Entity* object, and its type is *EllipsoidGraphics*.
A demo for this can found in the [Sphere and Ellipsoid](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Spheres%20and%20Ellipsoids.html) sandcastle example.

Comment: Thanks my friend for your answer, But If I want to use ray intersection 'var intersection = Cesium.IntersectionTests.rayEllipsoid(ray, ellipsoid);' I can not use entities Ellipsolid and it gives me error,How can I manage to fix it

Comment: Cannot convert EllipsoidGraphics to an Ellipsoid so should able to use the EllipsoidGraphics for display and separate Ellipsoid object for the ray tests.

Comment: thanks,But here I have a problem,When I create a Ellipsoid where does it locates? It seems it does not locates anywhere and ray intersection does not give me the same point each time..why?

Comment: There are not any examples of using Cesium IntersectionTests.rayEllipsoid() and Ellipsoid object in Sandcastle gallery or tutorials. Only reference is found in the [ray ref page](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Ray.html).

Comment: thanks dear friend, This is exactly my problem, I dont know how to intersect with an entity and it seems it is not possible :(, I really in need of this problem and I must solved it but can not figure out how